# Liquibase "rollback to tag mechanism" also deletes tag record. How come?

Tags: liquibase, rollback

My question is quite simple and its title is quite self-explanatory.

I ran Liquibase to rollback changesets to tag , everything worked as expected, but then I realized that **the tag record in itself was deleted from the DatabaseChangeLog table as well**.

I was expecting the tag record to remain in the table...
Is it just the way the rollback is supposed to proceed or did I miss a parameter or something that would allow the tag to be preserved?

Answer (score 2):

It was changed due to https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2815 with Liquibase 3.5.2/3.5.3

https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2946 was opened, because of new behavior.